# Auth-System easy way to do it like Amazon?

Tags: python, django, web, authentication

is there an easy way to configure the authentication system in Django like amazon 
does it?

If you are going to login in your amazon-account and the you are going to close your browser, even after two days when you are going on the webpage again, amazon is greeting you with your name. When you are going to shop, you still need to retype your password.

Is it possible to do it this way in Djanogo? Do I have to do something special in the settings.py?

As far as I know, I just can log in or out, even when I am going to close the browser, I am logged in again without any asking of my password.

Thanks for help!

Craphunter

Comment: It's called cookies: it stores your username on your computer. Yes, you can use it with Django (or just about anything). Note what else Amazon does, though: it "remembers" your name and preferences, but if you actually want to do anything significant, it asks for a password. That's clever design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation on sessions, in particular the section titled [Browser-length sessions vs. persistent sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions).

They explain precisely how to achieve what you're asking: `request.session.set_expiry(...)`.

Comment: This is not what he's asking. He wants the site to remember the last user that logged in but log them out after so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I think most likely what Amazon does is based on time and not on whether you close the browser or not.  So most likely what you should do is store in the session, the last time you saw that user.  If you saw them over an hour ago, then automatically log them out (use [Middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/middleware/) for this).

```
request.session['lastseen'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Now in your middlware just be careful in logging them out, as you still need to store their `id` or `username` in the session.  This is still easy to do, just read here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-out

So basically what you want to do is to logout a user, then after doing so, store their `id` or simply their `username` into the session so you can retrieve it later.  Doing a logout will completely clear their session, so you need to make sure to add their `id` or `username` *after* performing the `logout()` command.  Then wherever you want to retrieve that data you just pull it from the session variables.

```
logout(request.user)
request.session['userid'] = request.user.id
```

Then you now have three possibilities for a user: AnonymousUser w/out saved `id`, AnonymousUser w/ saved `id`, or Authenticated User.

This way even if someone isn't logged in, you still can get their `id` from the session.

Comment: If the session cookie is not persistent, then the browser will erase the cookie containing the session ID, which means the session will be dropped anyways. In particular, the `request.session['lastseen']` won't be available after the browser is closed.

Comment: Okay, is then there a way to do it like amazon?

Comment: @craphunter -- just make the session cookie persistent.  read the setup information about setting that.